# Android App Crashing. Async likely the cause

Tags: java, android, json

So I am making an Android app. Essentially what it does, is it fetches the user's longitude and latitude vid the network provider. It then passes that to a method which uses a geocoder to get back the zip code. Once I have the zip code, I make a request to WunderGround and get back the forecast a JSON. I then use GSON to parse it up, and get each Day's Date, Temp(F) and Conditions.

HOWEVER, my app keeps crashing, and I have no idea why. LogCat only tells me that it is in 'FutureTask'. I Googled that and it has something to do with threads, so I am assuming something in my Async is off.

If anyone can take a look at my code and give me some advice on how to fix this I would appreciate it.

CODE OMITTED (NO LONGER NECESSARY)

LOGCAT:

```
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): Local Branch: 
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): Remote Branch: 
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): Local Patches: 
02-20 22:53:38.632: I/Adreno-EGL(31953): Reconstruct Branch: 
02-20 22:53:42.846: E/dalvikvm(31953): Could not find class 'com.google.gson.JsonParser', referenced from method com.example.midterm2.MainActivity$parseJSON.doInBackground
02-20 22:53:42.846: W/dalvikvm(31953): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 738 (Lcom/google/gson/JsonParser;) in Lcom/example/midterm2/MainActivity$parseJSON;
02-20 22:53:42.886: W/dalvikvm(31953): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a0898)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonParser
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.example.midterm2.MainActivity$parseJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:197)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.example.midterm2.MainActivity$parseJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Post the logcat, please. That is a whole lot of code to sift through blindly.

Comment: Just looking at your code I can't find any problem in you AsyncTask execution, but are you executing another AsyncTask at the same time? This could cause a lot of strange problems...but as @codeMagic commented, please add your logcat

Comment: @codeMagic Posted. Please let me know if there is any more info you need. I am somewhat unfamiliar with logcat.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694117/why-cant-android-find-com-google-gson-gson

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17)

Comment: And [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging/18964524#18964524) about reading logcat.

Comment: How you added gson.jar? Add latest version. find in below link            https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you for the answer. That was one of the causes. There was one more offending line but it was an easy fix after reading the logcat. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome. You can upvote the answer(s) that helped solve the problem so they may help others easily

Answer (score 0):

According to the line that reads as

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonParser
02-20 22:53:42.936: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.example.midterm2.MainActivity$parseJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:197)
```

your GSON parser library isn't being packaged up in your APK properly.  You should probably double check your dependency configuration.

I'm not sure how you have your project set up, but question: [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22) would probably be helpful.